# Tensorflow batch processing with sparse matrices - can batch numbers be arbitrary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I am doing image recognition batch processing with sparse matrices in tensorflow. The only way I can find to pass a batch of sparse images into a session through a feed_dict is to make my sparse 3d images (x, y, colour) into sparse 4d images (batchNo, x, y, colour) and pass in indices, values, and shape.

This works fine but I have to continually create 4d images with the appropriate imageNumbers within the batch. What I am wondering is if I can create them all when I initially read in the data with arbitrary image numbers (e.g. 0-1000) then keep submitting 50 (say) picked as a batch from the shuffled data. The imageNumber would be unique for each image but not sequential or ordered. This would remove a big bottle neck from my code.

```
def getBatchOfImagesAndLabels(data, batchSize, singlePass = False):
    # Get a shuffled array of images and labels. 
    # Array length will be batchSize or smaller 
    #if we get to the end of the data on a singlePass
    # an image is a dictionary of indices, values, and shape.
    batch = data.next_batch(batchSize, singlePass)
    images = batch.images
    labels = batch.labels

    # Convert array of 3d sparse images into a 4d sparse matrix
    indices = []
    values = []
    shape = [len(labels)] + images[0]['shape']
    imageNumber=0
    for image in images:
        for ind in image['indices']: 
            indices.append([imageNumber] + ind)
        values.extend(image['values'])
        imageNumber += 1
    batchOfImages = {"indices": indices, "values": values, "shape": shape}
    return batchOfImages, labels
```

The for loop is very slow. Can I create the 4d sparse matrix when reading the data in and select slices from it which I believe would be quicker? The slices would have random, but unique, imageNumbers for each image in the batch.

Alternatively can some python guru suggest a clever way to make my for loop more efficient?